# Javascript: How to validate 4 relative fields to be greater than another

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, validation, field

So i have four fields that require some logic.

The logic must be like below, each field has to be greater than the one before. Let the [f1], [f2]... be the fields.

```
[f1] < [f2] < [f3] < [f4]
```

I have reached some crazy situation, because what if i have situation like this:

```
[null] < [null] < [null] < [f4]
```

And now i add a value to [f4] field. That means that the max value of f3 must be lower than f4 value

Now i add value to field f2

```
[null] < [f2] < [null] < [f4]
```

Oops! it also has to be lower than [f4], but if later i enter [f3] value, then it must be lower than [f3].
Same from the other, "GREATER THAN" side...

Is there any simple way to implement this instead of thousand of "if" clauses?

This is how i dynamically change the validation of any field:

```
  $("form").removeData("validator");
  $("#" + paramID).attr('data-val-range-max', valuemax)
  $("#" + paramID).attr('data-val-range-min', valuemin)
  $.validator.unobtrusive.parse(document);
```

EDIT:

The valid ending point is whether all of the elements have values or not, the valid endpoind is also like [5] < [null] < [null] < [10]

Comment: Perhaps [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Array.prototype.every, which test every element and breaks if one does not pass the test.

```js
function lessThan(array) {
    var a;
    array = array.filter(function (a) { // filter the array
        return a != null;               // return only values != null
    });
    a = array.shift();                  // get the first element by shifting the array
    return array.every(function (b) {   // return true if every element pass the test
        var r = a < b;                  // make the test
        a = b;                          // get the new comparing value for the next test
        return r;                       // return the test result
    });
}

document.write(lessThan([42]) + '<br>');                     // true (obviously!)
document.write(lessThan([0, 1, 2, 3]) + '<br>');             // true
document.write(lessThan([null, null, null, 4]) + '<br>');    // true
document.write(lessThan([null, 3, null, 4]) + '<br>');       // true
document.write(lessThan([0, 1, 0, 3]) + '<br>');             // false
document.write(lessThan([5, null, null, 4]) + '<br>');       // false
document.write(lessThan([null, null, null, null]) + '<br>'); // true
```

If you like, you can replace

```
var r = a < b;
a = b;
return r;
```

with

```
return [a < b, a = b][0];
```

which use a temporary array for storing the test result and assigning the last element to a.

Comment: thank you for the answer, now i have to figure out how to return true in case [null, 3, null, 4], because it is a valid one, i can have nulls between

Comment: what about all `null` values? and what about only length of one and only one number, like `[42]`? is [null, 42] true? can `null` be undefined, or `NaN`?

Comment: this worked best with some little edits, love it, thank you :)

Comment: if this answer helps you, you may considering to accept and/or upvote the answer. please have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

If the purpose is to find if the numbers are in ascendant order:

```
function lessThan(values){
     if(values.length < 2) throw new Error("Can't make comparison");
     var last = values[0],
         result;

    for(var i = 1; i < values.length; i++){
       result = last < values[i];
       last = values[i];
       if(!result) break;  
    }
    return result;
}

//lessThan([0,1,2,3]) === true;
//lessThan([0,1,0,3]) === false;
```